# How to populate table with foreign key values, using sequelize?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, associations

I have  models: Business, Contributor, Feedback.

I have created relationship between Feedback and Contributor, and Feedback and Business like this:

```
Feedback.belongsTo(Business)

Feedback.belongsTo(Contributor)
```

The corresponding foreign key attributes are added to the table Feedback. Question is, how to populate them with IDs coming from Business and Contributor table records?

This approach only gets the first record. If I use `findAll()`, then I get undefined.

```
for (let assetsUrl of assetUrls) {
  ...
  var businesses = null;
  var reviews = null;
  ...
  var timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  var b_id = await Business.findOne({
    attributes: ["id"],
  })
  var c_id = await Contributor.findOne({
  })

    businesses = await Business.upsert({
      ...
      last_scraped: timestamp
    });
    reviews = await Review.upsert(
      {
        contributor_id: c_id.id,
        business_id: b_id.id,
        last_scraped: timestamp,
      },
    )
  }
```

Business model:

```
class Business extends Model {}
Business.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    site: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    business_type: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
      defaultValue: "",
    },
    address: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      // allowNull defaults to true
    },
    price: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    url: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false, 
      unique: true,
    },
    last_scraped: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
      defaultValue: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "business",
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    underscored: true
  }
);

Business === sequelize.models.Business;
Business.sync();
```

Contributor model:

```
class Contributor extends Model {}
Contributor.init(
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    site: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    location: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    photo: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    url: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false, 
      unique: true,
    },
    status: {
      type: Sequelize.SMALLINT,
    },
    last_scraped: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
      defaultValue: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "contributor",
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    underscored: true,
  }
);

Contributor === sequelize.models.Contributor;
Contributor.sync();
```

Feedback model:

```
class Feedback extends Model {}
Feedback.init(
  {
    contributor_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    business_id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    date: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    rating: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    content: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      unique: false,
    },
    last_scraped: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER, 
      defaultValue: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
    },
  },
  {
    sequelize,
    modelName: "feedback",
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: false,
    updatedAt: false,
    underscored: true,
  }
);
Feedback.belongsTo(Contributor, { foreignKey: 'contributor_id' })
Feedback.belongsTo(Business, { foreignKey: 'business_id'})
Feedback=== sequelize.models.Review;
Feedback.sync();
```

Comment: Do you wish to get them from a database or insert/update into a database?

Comment: I wish the first option. Get them from the database, because they already exist when I want to populate table Feedback. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1):

A Good use case for model streaming but I think `sequelize` [doesn't 
support it yet](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/10347)

With your approch, using `findOne` combined with `offset` option you can 
create/update the `Feedback` model like this.

```
// Get number of records to avoid unnecessary findOne in the loop
const bRecordCount = await Business.count();
const cRecordCount = await Contributor.count();

for (let i = 0; i < assetUrls.length; i++) {
    const assetsUrl = assetUrls[i];

    // ...
    let bRecord = null;
    let cRecord = null;
    let options = {
        attributes: ["id"],
        // order by id to be sure we get different record each time
        order: [['id', 'ASC']],
        raw: true,
        offset: i //skip already taken records 
    };

    try {

        if (i < bRecordCount && i < cRecordCount) {
            bRecord = await Business.findOne(options)
            cRecord = await Contributor.findOne(options)
        }

        if (bRecord && cRecord) {
            feedback = await Feedback.upsert({
                contributor_id: cRecord.id,
                business_id: bRecord.id,
                last_scraped: timestamp,
                //...
            });
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

If you have many records you should consider using
[`findAll()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll) 
with `offset` and `limit` options,
then do a [`bulkCreate()`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-bulkCreate) 
with `updateOnDuplicate` option to avoid making many database queries

Comment: Something else must be the problem, because with your approach I am still having the same issue as I am having with the original code. The Feedback table is being populated, with the same `contributor_id` and `business_id` value for all records.

Comment: Please could you share the logs of `sequelize` SQL queries or your updated code 
to populate the `business` table?
Btw with the `order by id` and the `offset` set to the variable `i`, 
this should return different record from `business` and `contributor` tables
for each iteration

Answer (score 0):

To get Feedback items with certain attributes call **findAll**:

```
var feedback = await Feedback.findAll({
         attributes: ['contributor_id', 'business_id', 'last_scraped']
        })
```

Comment: I think we misunderstood. I need to create Feedback record that would consist of `contributor_id` and `business_id` fields. So, from the table Contributor I need to get ID and populate the `contributor_id` field in table Feedback. And the same for Business.

Comment: Ok, what records from Contributor and Business you wish to use and how do you get them?

Comment: I need to get one record at the time, so I used findOne.Here is the example for the business table: `var b_id = await Business.findOne({
          attributes: ["id"],
        })
        console.log(b_id)` But, upon inserting `b_id` it is giving me "incorrect integer value" error.

Comment: In this case `b_id` is an object with a prop `id`. So you should use `b_id.id`

Comment: That was very helpful, thank you. Now, the thing with findOne() is that it always give me just the first record from the database. If I use findAll(), then it gives me all record IDs in the list. And I need just one ID at the time. So, the problem is that ID=1 is inserted for all records.

Comment: Can you show a findAll query in the post? And also please add model definitions

Comment: I edited the original post with models definitions and findOne query. If, instead of findOne I add findAll, the ID is then undefined.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214360/discussion-between-anatoly-and-amabeat-30).